# Using <div> tag breaks the material UI Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I was trying to use `<div>` to wrap my element which is inside the `<Grid>` but i noticed that this will break my `<Grid>` !, i tried the same thing in bootstrap grid system but this issue did not occur,

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-6zet4?fontsize=14

The thing is i have to use div to give some style to my elements that are inside the `Grid` but as you can see in the `Codesandbox`, the `Grid` breaks after using the `div`, how can i handle this ?, should i use a replacement for `div` or is there some kind of props for `Grid` that can fix this?

Comment: did you find a way? here is similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70128120/layout-breaks-when-material-ui-grid-wrapped-in-div-element

Comment: @Nikita I ended up using bootstrap grid system instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the flexbox, it breaks because your div doesnt have the properties it needs.

```
.MuiGrid-grid-xs-12 {
    flex-grow: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

Adding this to the `div` will have the same result like giving the Grid the style property directly.

But the left,right and top border will be outside of the view, because of the `.MuiGrid-spacing-xs-3` class.

```
.MuiGrid-spacing-xs-3 {
    width: calc(100% + 24px);
    margin: -12px;
}
```

Depending on your needs use a different spacing like `0` for normal 100% width without margin and at it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect as result, but you can do is add `width:100%` to your div.
Another option would be to add the same classes a `Grid` has, that would be `MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12`

Result:
option 1 `<div style={{ border: "4px double black", width: '100%' }}>`

options 2 `<div className="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-xs-12" style={{ border: "4px double black" }}>`

Answer (score 0):

**Just add your border styles to `classes.paper`**

It seems from your example that you can just add the border to the paper inside the grid element to get the desired style.

```
paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: "center",
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    border: "4px double black"
  }
```

If you want multiple classes on an element, use string interpolation:

```
<Paper className={`${classes.paper1} ${classes.paper2}`}>
```