# Layout breaks when Material Ui grid wrapped in div element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, grid

I have responsive dashboard build with Material Ui `Grid` elements.
And one of the grid items wrapped in `div` element which breaks the layout.

Here is playground with `div` element - https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-material-demo-forked-pkkil?file=/demo.js

Here is playground without `div` element, and this how it should be with div - https://codesandbox.io/s/b1wsf?file=/demo.js

div element cannot be replaced or removed...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Mui `Grid` component is designed the way that `Grid container` should always be parent of `Grid item` prop. `Grid container` is cloning `Grid item` and passing to it additional configuration it is not based on react context.

Only sane way to get this working is to remove div.

Or provide custom css styles to this  to emulate grid spacing.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-material-demo-forked-pkkil?file=/demo.js